# Length - 1 takes off more then it should in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having an odd problem with my code. Every time the user goes to hit backspace it removes three numbers off the end. I am currently using $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, $(this).val().length - 1)); to take one number off the end but its removing more then it should. Did I do something wrong?

```
on('keydown keyup', '.type-date', function(e) {
        $(this).attr('maxlength', '10');
        var value = $(this).val();
        var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        if (!(key >= 0 && key <= 9))
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, $(this).val().length - 1));
        if (value.length == 2 || value.length == 5)
            $(this).val($(this).val() + '/');
        $('.type-date').attr('value', value);
    });
```

Comment: You have the function bound to `keyup` *and* `keydown` so it'll execute twice right there...

Comment: @tymeJV That would be the problem, thank you so much!

Comment: @tymeJV I spoke too soon! So I did try it and it still took off multiple numbers! Could this be a problem with the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is executed two time on `keydown` and then `keyup`. Just trigger function on `keyup`

```js
$('.type-date').on('keyup', function(e) {
        $(this).attr('maxlength', '10');
        var value = $(this).val();
        var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        if (!(key >= 0 && key <= 9))
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, $(this).val().length));
        if (value.length == 2 || value.length == 5)
            $(this).val($(this).val() + '/');
        $('.type-date').attr('value', value);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="type-date" />
```

Comment: So I did try this and it still took off more numbers then it should of. Could this be because of the browser or something else?

Comment: @Zachary you want to take off 2 letters?

Comment: No, I only want to be able to take off one at a time.

Comment: @Zachary ok now check it. Now its removing only 1 but when it reaches `/` it can't remove. Its due to some other code you have given. But now its removing only 1

Comment: That would make sense haha, well I guess I could just keep it. I thought it was broken but I guess it is all good. Thanks for the feedback!